# HTML <script> async Attribute in Magento

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, prototype, magento-1.9.1

I would like to try to insert the "async" attribute in Prototype JavaScript `script` tag in Magento 1.9.1:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/media/js/ec1651c8b1a4ea49a916679f1e120ccf.js"></script>
```

I would have this result:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/media/js/ec1651c8b1a4ea49a916679f1e120ccf.js" async></script>
```

Where I have to insert "async"? What is the file with this line code?
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look at the file `app/design/frontend/<yourlayout>/<yourtheme>/layout/page.xml` (or copy `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml` into your theme).

Inside this file, search for the following lines:

```
<!-- ... -->
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
    <!-- ... -->
</block>
<!-- ... -->
```

And change `addJs` calls by:

```
<!-- ... -->
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script><params>async</params></action>
    <!-- ... -->
</block>
<!-- ... -->
```

As your are using the merging javascript feature of magento, you need to apply this change to every `addJs` definition, because Magento will group files by `params`.

Comment: W3Shool says: The async attribute is only for external scripts (and should only be used if the src attribute is present).
So, why do you want to use it if the prototype is local?

Comment: @TonkBerlin I prefer to refer to the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) instead of W3School ;-) The think is `async` have sense only with script that have a `src` attribute (in opposition to inline script). In this case prototype.js is not included inline but loaded by the browser based on a `src` attribute.

Comment: Is it usefull to load the content without function if the .js is not loading?

Answer (score 0):

You make a small mistake.
This is actually the right answer for the question above.

```html
<!-- ... -->
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script><params>async="async"</params></action>
    <!-- ... -->
</block>
<!-- ... -->
```