# Magento: Load javascript async or defer

Tags: javascript, magento

I want to improve the loading speed of our pages, also based on the advice of Google.

So I want to use async or defer, so that javascript is not blocking the loading of the page.

I tried adding this to the javascript actions on our page.xml file, but that does break the loading of the javascript files on our shop.

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script><params>async</params></action>
```

How can achieve that javascript is loading after the entire page is loaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML <script> async Attribute in Magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658063/html-script-async-attribute-in-magento)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658063/html-script-async-attribute-in-magento